# xml parsing using sax

Tags: java, sax

I want to parse XML file using `SaxParser`. I'm trying to fetch the data associated to a tag or its attributes. The XML is in the following format.

```
 <con>
    <fig>
    <abc>
    <name xyz="">
    <id>2</id>
    </name>
    </abc>
    </fig>
  </con>
```

I tried with couple of example but not succeeded in the fetching the data, I am requesting you to provide me any suggestion or and working example to increase my knowledge on parsing using SAX.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOM parser as your xml is very small and its easy to get what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are my example and help available online, Please Google your question before posting on the stack over flow from next time.

Please check the following links which has good example for saxParsing

[How to read XML file in Java – (SAX Parser)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

[Getting Attributes And its Value](http://www.roseindia.net/xml/sax/ReadAttributes.shtml)

hope this help you.